# How to see verbose ggplot2 code executed (i.e. explicit declaration of ggplot2 defaults)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2's defaults are very convenient and help get things done quickly. But sometimes it can be necessary to want to see the assumptions ggplot2 is making more explicitly

#### Example

In the following plot, since the default colour/fill scale for ordered factors is viridis, we don't see any calls to `aes()` or `+ scale_colour_viridis_d()`, but we know something is happening for us behind the scenes, even though it's not explicit in the code

```
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
ggplot(dsamp, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = clarity))
```

[image]

#### Question

Is there a way to show a more verbose version of the ggplot2 code so that any defaults or assumptions are explicit in the code?

Note: the example is purely illustrative - it's easy enough to figure out what could been executed in the example, but I hope for an approach that **generalises** to any ggplot2 code

Comment: Maybe `ggplot_build` is what you need? Representative: `ggplot2::ggplot_build(ggplot2::ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,fill=Species)) + geom_bar())`. It actually doesn't tell us that much.

Comment: @NelsonGon very interesting to learn of `ggplot_build`. I'm not sure if it's output can be traced further to offer what we're after here?

Comment: +1, Occasionally, I end up stepping through the ggplot code to figure out exactly what it's doing, so I could determine how to tweak something slightly while mostly preserving the default behavior.  Although it might be good to include a list of what specifically would be useful to see.  E.g., default themes, functions used to compute default scales / labels / breaks, etc.?

Comment: @TimGoodman that sounds like a good idea, please feel free to edit the question to reflect this